# How to import Xgboost package from Github, into python 2.7 on windows 7?

Tags: python-2.7, github, xgboost

My system specs - Windows 7, python 2.7 Anaconda.
I am trying to import xgboost module from github.

```
import xgboost as xgb
```

ImportError: No module named xgboost

Please guide on how to link xgboost from github to my python library, or in general how to import any module from github to local library of Python/R.

Answer (score 0):

To easier your life.
This is a general way to setting python lib. 
Try "pip install xgboost" and "easy_install xgboost" in cmd first 
If not:

1:Download git and MINGW
2:After download you should set a path to save code of xgboost

```
$ cd /e/algorithm
```

3:Download xgboost with this code.

```
$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
$ cd xgboost
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
```

4:Open mingw and compile this project. And add path to enviroment.
5:Open bash and

```
$ which mingw32-make
to see if you can get path back
```

6:Compile xgboost
    enter xgboost path
    $ cd /e/algorithm/xgboost
7:Input following cmd to compile or you can write a bat or shell to save it.

```
$ cd dmlc-core
$ make -j4
$ cd ../rabit
$ make lib/librabit_empty.a -j4
$ cd ..
$ cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk
$ make -j4
```

8: Succeed